# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is an increasing sequence of of positive numbers such that $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty $. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify that the Cauchy criterion isn't satisfied: Since $(a_n)$ is monotonically increasing,

$$\sum_{n=k}^m \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n+1}} \geqslant \sum_{n=k}^m \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{m+1}} = \frac{a_{m+1}-a_k}{a_{m+1}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$ and $S_n=b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n=a_{n+1}-a_1$ so
$$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{b_n}{S_n+a_1}\sim_\infty\frac{b_n}{S_n}$$
but

$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{S_{n+1}}+\cdots+\frac{b_{n+p}}{S_{n+p}}\ge\frac{b_{n+1}+\cdots+b_{n+p}}{S_{n+p}}=\frac{S_{n+p}-S_n}{S_{n+p}}\xrightarrow{p\to\infty}1$$
so by the Cauchy criterion the series $\sum\frac{b_n}{S_n}$ is divergent so the given series is also divergent by comparison.